# Aborta Pharo recien instalado

Tags: pharo, smalltalk

Acabo de instalar `PHARO` y al tratar de abrir en `playground` me da un error:

> PrimitiveFailed: primitive #primSize: in MultiByteFileStream failed.

Si trato de hacer `QUIT` me da el error:

> PrimitiveFailed: primitive #primGetPosition: in MultiByteFileStream
>   failed.

Lo estoy corriendo en un MAC Sistema Versión 10.12 (915)

¿Serviría des-instalarlo y volverlo a instalar? ¿Como hago esto?

Lo he abortado y vuelve a dar los mismos errores. ¿Que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2):

buenas,
cómo lo instalaste?

El caso normal es bajarlo de acá: http://pharo.org/web/download

1. cómo no esta firmado, vas a tener que aceptar la ejecución
2. cómo Sierra ejecuta todo lo que no está en /Applications en un sandbox, deberías poner Pharo.app ahí.

Si a pesar de todo no anda, hay otras formas de hacerlo arrancar... pero empecemos por acá :)